# Find all 100 digit numbers for which x/F(x) attains its maximum value.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $F(x)$ be the sum of digits of $x$. Find all positive integers $x$ with $100$ digits for which $\frac {x}{F(x)}$  attains its maximum value among all 100-digit integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all sequences $(d_0,\ldots,d_{99})$ of non-negative numbers (and in particular for sequences of digits) one obviously has $\sum_{i=0}^{99}d_i10^i\leq\sum_{i=0}^{99}d_i10^{99}$, with equality only if $d_0,\ldots,d_{98}$ are all zero. It follows that $$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{99}d_i10^i}{\sum_{i=0}^{99}d_i}\leq10^{99}$$
with equality only if $0=d_0=\cdots=d_{98}$. Therefore the maximum is $10^{99}$ and is attained for $x=d_{99}10^{99}$ with $d_{99}\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, and for no other numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\frac x{F(x)}=10^{99}$ for $x=d\cdot 10^{99}$, $d=1,2,\ldots,9$.
For any other number $x=d\cdot 10^{99}+y$ (with $0<y<10^{99}$, so $x<(d+1)\cdot 10^{99}$) in that range, $F(x)\ge d+1$, so $\frac{x}{F(x)}<10^{99}$.

Comment: ok, added somewhere